# Failure to install HTSeq Python package on Ubuntu 14.04

Tags: python-2.7, numpy, matplotlib, ubuntu-14.04

I need to use a program called HTSeq. There are detailed instructions for the installation, but as I am a new Python user I must have messed up somewhere.

I first tried to install under Windows XP but I kept getting the error below, even after installing `vcredist_x86.exe`:

```
>>> import HTSeq
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\HTSeq\__init__.py", line 9, in <module> from _HTSeq import *
ImportError: DLL load failed: Le module specifie est introuvable.
```

Since I really prefer the Unix environment, I gave up with Windows and installed Ubuntu 14.04, and then tried again. In the Terminal, I entered:

```
sudo apt-get install build-essential python2.7-dev python-numpy python-matplotlib
```

I obtained a series of errors because the proxy wasn't set up properly. Since that didn't work, I decided to download `Python-2.7.9.tgz` and install it with

```
.configure
make
sudo make install
```

Meanwhile I discovered that the proxy was set wrong and edited `apt.conf` accordingly. I repeated the command

```
sudo apt-get install build-essential python2.7-dev python-numpy python-matplotlib
```

and everything installed perfectly.
Then I downloaded `HTSeq-0.6.1p1` and unpacked it in a new directory I named `opt`. I tried to install and got this error:

```
liz@liz-Veriton-M670G:~/opt/HTSeq-0.6.1p1$ python setup.py install --user
    Could not import 'setuptools', falling back to 'distutils'.
Setup script for HTSeq: Failed to import 'numpy'.
Please install numpy and then try again to install HTSeq.
```

Numpy is installed, as indicated by:

```
liz@liz-Veriton-M670G:~/opt/HTSeq-0.6.1p1$ sudo apt-get install python-numpy
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
python-numpy is already the newest version.
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 391 not upgraded.
```

So only setuptools appears to be missing. I do

```
liz@liz-Veriton-M670G:~$ sudo apt-get install python-setuptools
```

But HTSeq still does not install.

```
liz@liz-Veriton-M670G:~$ cd ./opt/HTSeq-0.6.1p1/
liz@liz-Veriton-M670G:~/opt/HTSeq-0.6.1p1$ python setup.py install --user
Could not import 'setuptools', falling back to 'distutils'.
Setup script for HTSeq: Failed to import 'numpy'.
Please install numpy and then try again to install HTSeq.
```

Maybe I did not install things in the right directories?  What did I do wrong?

Answer (score 1):

Probably things are bit messed up now; maybe you now have two Python installations.

Write `/usr/bin/python` instead of just `python` to ensure that you use the one installed by `apt-get`.

And start Python once (just type `/usr/bin/python`) and then type `import numpy` to see whether it can be loaded.

Comment: Yes indeed, very messed up. I tried to remove everything and start over with sudo apt-get remove but I cannot remove Python. > which python gives me /usr/local/bin/python. I have python2.7 and 3.4 in both /usr/bin/ and /usr/local/bin. Is there a way to launch 2.7 instead of 3.4?

Answer (score 0):

Indeed, since there was a version of Python that came with my Ubuntu installation, I wound up with multiple versions in both /usr/bin and /usr/local/bin.
But it suffices to launch the proper one and HTSeq installed:

> liz@liz-Veriton-M670G:~$ cd ./Desktop/HTSeq-0.6.1p1/
>
> liz@liz-Veriton-M670G:~/Desktop/HTSeq-0.6.1p1$ /usr/bin/python setup.py install --user

Thank you for such a simple answer!